# Email confirmation issue after ajax validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7.4 and PHP 7.4.

I've a Laravel default Registration form. After submit, it sends the verification email to user to complete the registration process. After verification, user can visit the **dashboard** page. Now I want to apply my validation using ajax and get JSON response from RegisterController. I simply wrote a **postRegister** function to handle validation.

**Issue:**

My validation is working but only the issue is after registration, user can access the **dashboard** page without email confirmation. If I remove validation function, now the user can only access the dashboard after email confirmation.

1. I want to validate my form but not bypassing the email confirmation step.
2. After submit, how would I redirect a user to verify-email page.

What is the best approach?

Blade

```
<form name="register_name" id="register_forms">
    <input  name="register_name" type="text" />
    ..............
    <input id="my-register" type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
    $("#my-register").click(function(e){
/**Ajax code**/
         e.preventDefault();
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
           }
       });
        $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{{ route('register') }}",
     data: $('#register_forms').serialize(),
     dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        if (err.status == 422) { 
            $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(err.responseJSON.message);

            // display errors on each form field
            $.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {
                var el = $(document).find('[name="'+i+'"]');
                el.after($('<span style="color: #ff0000;">'+error[0]+'</span>'));
            });
        }
    }
});
/**Ajax code ends**/
    });
```

RegisterController

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'register_email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],

    ]);
    $validator->setAttributeNames([
        'register_email' => 'email',
    ]);

    return $validator;
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
  $user = User::create([
      'email' => $data['register_email'],
  ]);

  $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

  return $user;
}

public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('auth/register')->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard')->middleware('verified');
```

Comment: does your `User` model implement the `MustVerifyEmail` interface?

Comment: @lagbox yes, here it is "class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
"